# Configuration Errors With A Clean Installation of Apache Directory Studio

Tags: ldap

I have a fresh install of Apache Directory Studio, with the goal of sanity testing some LDAP stuff without actually touching production.

I followed the basic instructions to spin-up the server and it fails to launch.  Diving into the logs I see the following

```
[11:57:28] INFO [org.apache.directory.server.UberjarMain] - Starting the service.
[11:57:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[11:57:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.841' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[11:57:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.2' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[11:57:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[11:57:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.528' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[11:57:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService] - You didn't change the admin password of directory service instance 'default'.  Please update the admin password as soon as possible to prevent a possible security breach.
[13:21:17] INFO [org.apache.directory.server.UberjarMain] - Starting the service.
```

Has anyone else experienced similar issues?  And if not, can they share what their current JRE version is in collaboration with Apache Directory Studio?

I'm trying to determine if this is an issue with the installed version of JAVA, an issue with the application or more likely a combination there of

Comment: I do not see there any error showing it fails to start, only warnings. The last line clearly shows 'starting the service'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a ton of serverfault pages and searching around, it appears you need to use OpenJDK 11 or it's a no go